Why isn't my Unity rotation check working?
The problem
I have code that is meant to, upon spawning, set a swinging weapon to one side of the sweeping edge range, rotate it every frame, and then check if it swings to far and destroy it if it does. The spawning and rotating work fine, but no matter how I configure the if statement that checks the rotation amount, it either doesn't work, or instantly destroys the object.
What I have already tried
I have tried every combination of:

Negating the sweeping edge variable
Flipping the comparison sign
Negating the variable where it sets the rotation at the start
Changing the direction of the swing
Any other methods for troubleshooting or other solutions would be extremely appreciated. For reference the code within the Update function is below.

Reference code
if (delayTimer > 0 && !hasStarted) {  //Note: This if statement is necessary so that the code doesn't try to initialize until the variables are set
            if (weapon == null) {  // Note: Weapon is a variable used to hold the weapon data like damage and sweeping edge range
                Debug.Log("No weapon referenced.");
                return;
            }
            Debug.Log("Found weapon");
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, weapon.attackRange + 0.5f, 1);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -weapon.sweepingEdgeRange / 2);
            transform.Translate(0, transform.localScale.y / 2, 0);
            hasStarted = true; //Note: This prevents the initialization from running more than once
        }
        delayTimer++; //Note: Necessary for initialization
        transform.Translate(0, -transform.localScale.y / 2, 0);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 0.5f);
        transform.Translate(0, transform.localScale.y / 2, 0);
        if (transform.rotation.z >= weapon.sweepingEdgeRange) {
            Debug.Log("Too far!");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

I have also noticed that the Rotate() function Rotates the opposite direction of the number inputted, but I tried to account for that with negation and it didn't work. (see the section which said what I tried)
EDIT: SOLVED
Using various elements and general ideas from the answers on this post, I managed to make a solution. The first mistake was that I was unknowingly using a Quaternion. mikyll98's answer helped me with that and suggested I used the localRotation euler angles. I implemented that but then the next problem was that those are always positive, so because I was swinging into the negative direction it would just loop around and never stop. I fixed this by checking if it was greater than the positive, but not greater than 180 (so that it doesn't disappear imediately.) The fixed code is shown below. Thanks to all who helped!
if (transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z >= weapon.sweepingEdgeRange && transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z <= 180) {
    Debug.Log("Too far!");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}


Please edit the question to remove the answer and post it below as a self-answer.

I think the issue is in the last if condition: transform.rotation is a
Quaternion,
which is not directly comparable to the (I suppose) scalar value of
weapon.sweepingEdgeRange. Therefore, you should instead obtain the
angle of rotation, around the z-axis.
For example, you could use transform.localEulerAngles,
which is

The rotation as Euler angles in degrees relative to the parent transform's rotation.

// We use 'z' component for rotation around z axis
float currentRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z;

if (currentRotation < 0)
{
  currentRotation += 360;
}

if (currentRotation >= weapon.sweepingEdgeRange || 
  currentRotation <= -weapon.sweepingEdgeRange)
{
  Debug.Log("Too far!");
  Destroy(gameObject);
}


Hello, thanks for the solution, however this doesn't work for me. I implemented your code but it has the problem where it just instantly says it went too far. I have tried the usual of negating and flipping directions etc for everything but it always either disappears immediately or never stops.

I just edited my question as I found a solution. Thanks for the help!

You need to use eulerAngles. Fixed code:
if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < weapon.sweepingEdgeRange) {
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 0.5f);


I just edited my question as I found a solution. Thanks for the help!
